# How to make an editable catalog on Drupal?

Tags: views, nodes

I'm trying to make something like an catalog (e.g. an address book) on my site, in which the user can interact with the fields, like adding, editing and removing entries, I'm thinking about putting each of those entries as a content type node and then using views to display and modify them... Is there any known problem with this approach? could you suggest another one?

I want it to be dynamic, on click the selected entry expands allowing for editing and automatically saves the content...

Comment: Hello. Your question still asks for "the standard Drupal way" and while for low-level things such standards are defined (like code formatting standard), any "standards" for such high level functionality would be a mere opinion. Now, if you would ask "How to make an editable catalog?" and provide rough idea of what you want and what Drupal tools you considered, it would be pretty OK question. I'm sad to click "Leave Closed" and hope to see your post in the queue again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing todo is to make a View thats lists your catalog entries. In the `Header` area of the view add a `global text area` in which you create a link such as `<a href="/node/add/YOUR_CATALOG_ENTRY_NODE_TYPE">Add New Entry</a>`.

Then also install the [Editable Views](https://drupal.org/project/editableviews) module:

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited.
>   Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save'
>   button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.
>
> Editable fields can be added on the base entity as well as on entities
>   brought into the View by a relationship. Other, non-editable fields
>   may be added to the View, in which case they function normally.

From the project page you can see a [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_D4z4Bw6iw) on how to use the Editable Views module.